# Where is the interp function in numpy.core.multiarray located?

Tags: python, numpy

The [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1432-L1570) for [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) calls a [`compiled_interp`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1543) function which is apparently the `interp` function [imported](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L26) from `numpy.core.multiarray`.

I went looking for this function but I can not find it [inside that file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/core/multiarray.py).

What am I missing?

Comment: The implementation is in C. This might be it but not 100% sure https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `interp` Python function of `numpy.core.multiarray` is exported in [multiarraymodule.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3a17c9698451906018856972e9aa08c9b626aa9c/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4445). It is mapped to `arr_interp` which is a C function defined in [compiled_base.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L492). The heart of the computation can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L600).